# My code works only when the input is below 31 [ProjectEuler100] problem #10-Summation of primes

Tags: python, primes

The problem is from Project Euler100.

My code is supposed to find the summation of primes below n.

It works fine only when the n is below 31.

When n is 32 I still got 129, when n is 2001, I STILL got 129.
(The sum of primes below 29 and including 29 is 129, so if n is 32, it is supposed to return 160.)

I don't understand why...
Here is my code (python)

```
# Except 2 and 3, primes are written in the form of 6k±1.(edited)
import math

def is_prime(number):
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(number))+1):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False
        else:
            continue
    return True

def prime_summation(n):
    prime_sum = 0
    prime_i = [5, 7]

    if int(n) == 3:
        prime_sum = 2
    elif int(n) < 5 and int(n) > 3:
        prime_sum = 5
    elif int(n) >= 5:
        prime_sum = 5  #2 + 3 = 5
        for prime in prime_i:
            while prime < int(n) and is_prime(prime):

                prime_sum += prime
                prime += 6

    return prime_sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = input("Sum of primes below n, n ?: ")
    print(prime_summation(n))
```

Comment: Aren't integers of the form `6k ± 1` pseudo-prime? 6*4 + 1 = 25, which obviously isn't prime. Every prime may be written as 6k ± 1, but not every integer i = 6k ± 1 is prime.

Comment: @vonludi yep. I wrote a wrong statement about primes. My bad.  Not every 6k±1 is a prime. that's why I check if the number is prime using `is_prime`.

Comment: Print out the primes you've found and check that you are adding all the primes up to n? If not, you have something to debug...

Comment: @PaulHankin Yes that's how I found the bug! thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems to work if you rewrite it like that (do not break out of the `while`-loop if you encounter any pseudo-primes that are non-prime, e.g. 25).

```py
def prime_summation(n):
    n = int(n)

    prime_i = [5, 7]
    prime_sum = 0

    if n == 3:
        prime_sum = 2
    elif n == 4:
        prime_sum = 5
    elif n >= 5:
        prime_sum = 5  #2 + 3 = 5
        for prime in prime_i:
            while prime < n:
                if is_prime(prime):
                    prime_sum += prime
                prime += 6
    return prime_sum
```

Comment: With integers, `elif 3 < n < 5:` actually means `elif n == 4:`

Comment: As does `elif int(n) < 5 and int(n) > 3:` in the original question.

Comment: That I wasn't changing logic of the code in the question here, so I do not see the point in your comment.

Comment: My point was that you made an improvement on the original code (changing how the numbers are compared), but you could improve it even more by making the explicit comparison, just like the `if n == 3:` line

Comment: I included your feedback now.

Comment: Oh! We found the same solution at the same time! (almost! I think you were 3 seconds faster. lol) Thanks. Your comments about 25 = 6*4+1 gave me an idea

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, guys lol
because I set the condition of `while` loop like this:
`while prime < int(n) and is_prime(prime)`

It stops the loop after 25 (25 = 6*4 +1).

I changed my code to:

```
 while prime < int(n):
                if is_prime(prime):
                    prime_sum += prime
                prime += 6
```

and it works!

Answer (score -2):

The same solution written in Go:

```golang
package problem10

import (
    "log"
    "math"

    "github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils/helper"
    mathutils "github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils/math"
)

// IsPrime is delegated to verify if the given number is prime
func IsPrime(n int) bool {
    if n <= 3 {
        return n > 1
    } else if n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0 {
        return false
    }
    i := 5
    mult := float64(2)
    for int(math.Pow(float64(i), mult)) <= n {
        if n%i == 0 || n%(i+2) == 0 {
            return false
        }
        i += 6
    }
    return true
}

func CalculatePrime(max int) {
    // generate an array of sequential number like [1,2,3,4,5,..., max]
    array := helper.GenerateSequentialIntArray(max)
    var prime []int
    for i := 0; i < len(array); i++ {
        if IsPrime(array[i]) {
            prime = append(prime, array[i])
        }
    }
    // Sum all the value present in the array -> [1,3,5] --> 9
    log.Println(mathutils.SumIntArray(prime))
}
```

https://github.com/alessiosavi/GoProjectEuler

Comment: This does not explain why the posted code doesn't work, and it's not even in the same language as the original question. The person asking might not even know the go language

Comment: Is just for an algorithm POV. As you can see, here is only math. No particular "magic" library used. You can view as a pseudocode due to the low complexity of the problem.